# Nav Bar Text aligned on left

Tags: html, css

I have finally achieved making a nav bar with text aligned left with small spaces between. I think using flex items is not the best way. Please show me how to align the nav bar with spaces between on the left

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
<body>
    <nav class="container">
        <p class="item1">Events</p>
        <p class="item2">Results</p>
        <p class="item3">Partnering Restaurants</p>
    </nav>
</body>

    *{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    border: solid black 1px;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: blue;
}
.item1{
    flex: 0.1;
}
.item2{
    flex: 0.1;
}
.item3{
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your navbar has links so the best semantic tag for the link is `<a>`.

If you put `<a>` instead of `<p>` you don't need to add flexbox styling as `a` is an inline element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

.container {
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: aqua;
  color: blue;
  padding: 12px;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="container">
  <a class="item1" href="page1">Events</a>
  <a class="item2" href="page2">Results</a>
  <a class="item3" href="page3">Partnering Restaurants</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    border: solid black 1px;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: blue;
}

nav p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="container">
        <p class="item1">Events</p>
        <p class="item2">Results</p>
        <p class="item3">Partnering Restaurants</p>
    </nav>
```

Since `nav` have links, use `<a>` instead of `<p>`. So you `nav` markup should be something similar to this:

```
  <nav class="container">
    <a class="item1" href="#">Events</a>
    <a class="item2" href="#">Results</a>
    <a class="item3" href="#">Partnering Restaurants</a>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

please clear your question
but here is solution i find

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  </head>
 
  <body>
      <nav class="container">
          <p class="item1">Events</p>
          <p class="item2">Results</p>
          <p class="item3">Partnering Restaurants</p>
      </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is css

```
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 2%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    border: solid black 1px;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: blue;
}
.container > *{
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

what i changes i maked

padding on top and bottom
no need of this

```
.item1{
    flex: 0.1;
}
.item2{
    flex: 0.1;
}
.item3{
    flex: 1;
}
```

use this >*

here is the sample
[image]